# Incompatible pointer types initializaing NSString with NSURL*

Tags: objective-c

I was changing NSTemporaryDirectory to NSCache directory and most of the code happen the next error:

```
- (BOOL)isDirectory:(NSString *)path {
NSString *pathToFile = NSTemporaryDirectory();

NSString *result = [pathToFile stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"shows"];
result = [result stringByAppendingPathComponent:path];


BOOL isDir;

return [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:result
                                            isDirectory:&isDir];
}
```

I changed to:

```
    - (BOOL)isDirectory:(NSString *)path {
        NSURL *urlToFile = [NSFileManager.defaultManager
                        URLForDirectory:NSCachesDirectory inDomain:NSUserDomainMask
                        appropriateForURL:nil create:YES error:NULL];

NSURL *result = [urlToFile URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"shows"];
result = [result URLByAppendingPathComponent:path];


        BOOL isDir;

        return [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:result
                                                    isDirectory:&isDir];
    }
```

And this warning appeared that crashed my app:

```
Incompatible pointer types initializing 'NSString *' with an expression of type 'NSURL * _Nullable'
```

Answer (score 1):

As the error (and the API) clearly states the result of `URLForDirectory...` is an `NSURL`

```
NSURL *urlToFile = [NSFileManager.defaultManager
                        URLForDirectory:NSCachesDirectory inDomain:NSUserDomainMask
                        appropriateForURL:nil create:YES error:NULL];

NSURL *result = [urlToFile URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"shows"];
result = [result URLByAppendingPathComponent:path];
```

To get a string path back call `path` on the URL

```
NSString *resultPath = result.path;
```

However the URL related API is preferable.

Comment: I changed what you said, but still the same problem, I update with the complete function maybe you can help me

Comment: *I changed what you said*. No, you didn’t. Please read my answer carefully.

Comment: oh sorry, I did all fast without thinking thanks for the support, I'll try to change all the other things